# Marginally Outer Trapped Surface as a Minimal Surface

Tags: general-relativity, minimal-surfaces

In general relativity, a marginally outer trapped surface is defined to be a spacelike, two-dimensional surface in a space-time such that outgoing null rays perpendicular to the surface are do not diverge or converge.

Under what circumstances is a MOTS the same as a minimal surface?  Does the trace of the second fundamental form $k$ need to vanish as well as the normal-normal component $k_{nn}$?